# Migrating an Arduino Project to Beetle Bluno

Tags: arduino-uno

So I have a working project with Arduino Uno. I now want to migrate it to the Beetle Bluno[image: The bluno beetle]. I tried running the code on the Beetle and it does work. I cannot seem to get the Bluetooth to work though. The code is below:

```
#include <Bounce2.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#include <Wire.h>
//SoftwareSerial bluetooth_port(10, 11);

// Connect each button with one connection
// to GND and the other to a digital pin.
const byte buttonPinBLE1 = 2;
const byte buttonPinBLE2 = 3;

class Button{

  private:

    byte m_buttonPin;
    byte m_counter = 0;
    unsigned long m_buttonPressTimeout;
    unsigned long m_previousMillis;

  public:

    Button(byte buttonPin):
      m_buttonPin(buttonPin),
      m_counter(0),
      m_buttonPressTimeout(1500), // Button press timeout in ms.
      m_previousMillis(0){}

    void Update(){
      if(m_counter > 0 && millis() - m_previousMillis >= m_buttonPressTimeout)
      {
        //Serial.print("Count from Update() just before it's reset to 0 = ");
        Serial.println(GetCounter());
        m_counter = 0;
      }
    }

    void IncrementCounter(){
      m_counter++;
      if(m_counter > 4){m_counter = 4;}
      if(m_counter == 1)
      {
        m_previousMillis = millis();
      }
    }

    friend void IncrementCounter(Button&);

    void IncrementCounter(Button&){
      IncrementCounter();
    }

    byte GetCounter(){
      return m_counter;
    }

};

Bounce buttonOneDebouncer = Bounce();
Bounce buttonTwoDebouncer = Bounce();
Button ButtonOne(buttonPinBLE1);
Button ButtonTwo(buttonPinBLE2);

void setup(){
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(buttonPinBLE1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPinBLE2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  buttonOneDebouncer.attach(buttonPinBLE1);
  buttonTwoDebouncer.attach(buttonPinBLE2);
  buttonOneDebouncer.interval(25);
  buttonTwoDebouncer.interval(25);
}

void loop(){

  // Call the Update function as fast as possible.
  ButtonOne.Update();
  ButtonTwo.Update();

  // Button one pressed.
  if(buttonOneDebouncer.update()){
    if(buttonOneDebouncer.fell()){
      if(digitalRead(buttonPinBLE2) == 0){
        ButtonOne.IncrementCounter();
      }
    }
  }

  // Button two pressed.
  if(buttonTwoDebouncer.update()){
    if(buttonTwoDebouncer.fell()){
      if(digitalRead(buttonPinBLE1) == 0){
        ButtonOne.IncrementCounter(ButtonTwo);
      }
    }
  }
  if(digitalRead(buttonPinBLE1) == 0 && (digitalRead(buttonPinBLE2) == 0))
  {
  Serial.println("9");
  }

}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the device to communicate with my computer via Bluetooth? I have no experience with the Beetle and I cannot seem to find much help online.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103422/discussion-on-question-by-user19964-migrating-an-arduino-project-to-beetle-bluno).

Comment: @VE7JRO Hello. You helped me with the single tap, double tap question (https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/69897/detecting-how-many-button-pressessingle-tap-double-tap-etc-with-two-simultane). Thank you so much for that once more. However, it isn't accurate and sometimes if i press the buttons once, it outputs a 2, sometimes it outputs a 4 when i press it twice. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: The original code I provided in the linked Q+A worked perfectly on a Arduino Uno. The sketch you are using in this question is different. I do not have a Beetle Bluno to test with, so I'm sorry, but I can't help you. If I can't test the sketch on the "same" hardware, then I'm just guessing, not answering.

Comment: @VE7JRO the code I am using is on an Arduino Uno...it isn't working accurately for some reason on my side. I haven't started using the Beetle as yet so still testing on the Arduino Uno